# Pass an object in a redirection

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use `$location` for redirecting to one of the page of my app by providing an object of my `$scope`.

Here is a simplified version of what I'm trying to achieve:

**HTML**

```
<div>
    Name: {{bruce.name}} 
    E-mail: <a ng-click="contact(bruce)">{{bruce.mail}}</a>
</div>
```

**In my Angular controller**

```
$scope.bruce = {name: 'Bruce Wayne', mail: 'brucewayne@batman.com'}

/* Should redirect to mail page with dest object */
$scope.contact = function(dest) {
    $location.path("/mail");
    // Provide dest object
}
```

---

In the second page (*which has a different controller*), I would like to be able to show the sended object:

```
<div>
     <p>From: mymail@me.com <br/>       
     To: {{dest.mail}}</p>

     <p>Type your email...</p>
</div>
```

---

I guess the solution is really simple, so I don't need a full working code, but I would appreciate some ideas for how to achieve this.

*PS: A solution without using `$location` may suit me as well.*

Comment: You need to look into Angular Services - they'll help persist data between pages in a SPA design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a typical scenario where you share data inside your application.
A potential solution should be this:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.service('myService', function(){
  var data;
  this.setData = function(d){
    data = d;
  }
  this.getData = function(){
    return data;
  }
});

app.controller('myCtrl1', function($scope, myService){
 ..
 myService.setData(objectSent);

});

app.controller('myCtrl2', function($scope, myService){
 $scope.objectSent= myService.getData();
 //do something
});
```

Services are singleton, are instantiated once and then cached by angular, everytime you need that specific data you can inject the service and call the methods provided.